# about polymorphism small concern

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to check some polymorphism scenarios. In my code class `B` has `bb` virtual method and Class `C` also has same `bb` method but this is normal.

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C ccc = new C();
        ccc.aa();
        ccc.bb();
        ccc.cc();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class A
{
    public virtual void aa() => Console.WriteLine("a");
}
public class B : A
{
    public virtual void bb() => Console.WriteLine("b");
}
public class C : B
{
    public virtual void cc() => Console.WriteLine("c");
    public void bb() => Console.WriteLine("bvv");
}
```

When I run the code my output is

```
a
bvv
c
```

But I have not override the parent class member of class `B` method `bb`
why the system calling `C` class `bb` member that should call `B` class `bb`.

What happened?

Comment: You should get a compiler warning for this. Look up the difference between `new` and `overrides`. I'm sure you'll fine plenty.

Comment: please see this simple tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism

Comment: actually my question is if sombody having two class like A and B sapose a class having one method virtual a1 and B class having same method a1 in child class A is parent of B so when i create the object of B class and try to coll the a1 method whic one will exicute. A claas a1 or B class a1 ?

Comment: Look at the output from the compiler & you will see this _"warning CS0114: 'C.bb()' hides inherited member 'B.bb()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword."_ It clearly says the second definition hides the first.

Comment: No, i have tryed with new key work it working as previous. but what i am tryinhg is using c class object coll the B class bb member. it is possible or not ?

Comment: If you want to call the B base class bb method from within any of the C class methods, then you can call base.bb(). From the instance of class C cc you cannot access any overridden or hidden methods.

Comment: thanks, base working well

Answer (score 0):

Following by the MSDN C#
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier

> Name hiding through inheritance takes one of the following forms:
>
> A method introduced in a class or struct hides properties, fields, and
>   types that share that name in the base class. It also hides all base
>   class methods that have the same signature.

So, you can use the new keyword on class C or class C override B by default

```
class C : B
{
    public virtual void cc() => Console.WriteLine("c");
    public new void bb() => Console.WriteLine("bvv");
}
```

Comment: No, i have tryed with new key work it working as previous. but what i am tryinhg is using c class object coll the B class bb member. it is possible or not ?

Comment: Yes, in method bb of class C, you call write like this : public void bb()
    {
    base.bb();
    }